# Failed to load error when trying to fetch some JSON file from GitHub repo

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, git, github

I am currently learning JSON and AJAX and stumbled on a problem when loading simple JSON file from a repo on GitHub.

I am using browser sync to set up local server and here is the code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open(
    "GET",
    "https://github.com/d-ivashchuk/misc/blob/master/ancestry.json",
    false
);
request.onload = function() {
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    console.log(data[3]);
};
request.send();
```

The error is:

> Failed to load. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the resource.

As I was able to download some JSON files from GitHub, I know that it is possible, but still want to know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Learn about the Same-Origin policy.  You can't do that.

Comment: @SLaks So I can basically fetch JSON files only from my own domain, or from ones that allowed me to do so explicitly?

Comment: Just for the record, your code works, you just need to use the `raw` url...look at this example https://jsfiddle.net/xejx2jgx/

Comment: @Hackerman amazing, thanks! Is this solution also suitable for getting data from other sources apart from git?

Comment: Nope....in this case, github allow `CORS`...if you look at the response headers from the `raw.github` url, the following header is present `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

Comment: @Hackerman understood, thanks for definitive answer!

Comment: Glad to help @DimitryIvashchuk

Comment: @Hackerman you might want to write an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the `raw` version of your file; with that you just need a minor fix in order to make it work:

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open(
  "GET",
  //The right url
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d-ivashchuk/misc/master/ancestry.json",
  false
  );
  request.onload = function() {
  var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  console.log(data[3]);
  };
  request.send();
```

You can see it working here: <kbd>[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xejx2jgx/1/)</kbd>

And about your other question: `Is this solution also suitable for getting data from other sources apart from git?`, the short answer is **no**...but, you can use this solution with any source that allows `CORS`, like for example, if you inspect the headers from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d-ivashchuk/misc/master/ancestry.json`, you can see that the following header is present `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`